# Any tool to automatically generate HTML layout structure diagram?

Tags: software-recommendation, html, data-visualisation

I usually post in StackOverflow, but this is more a layout/design question. I am trying to get an overview of the HTML structure of an application I am working on, and was looking for a tool to automatically generate a diagram of the layout/ordering. Does anybody use such a tool?

It would be great to see the layers, or a UML type diagram, showing the order of the parent/child elements in relation to each other.

What I've found:

- Chrome DevTools Layers Panel (in experimental state, and barely usable)
- FireFox 3D View - Using the Tilt plugin (looks very impressive, but is more visual than practical)

[image: Example of FireFox Tilt plugin]

Comment: UML is not designed to work with HTML for as far as I know, I've tried to make it work but that is just not very convenient. Do you want it to look great visually or do you want to model it for your co-workers (what UML is meant for)? Firefox obviously checks your CSS before it creates the model, wich I think is relevant if you want to see the `z-index` and stuff like that.

Comment: Remember that the "layer" concept on an html page is only a marketing term used by dreamweaver. There are not "layers" but nested elements.

Comment: @Rafael They are referred to as layers by development teams, and the Google DevTool is called Layers Panel. Also, Mozilla documentation refers to layers in most of their css z-index documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Comment: @Randy I used uml as an example only. It's for documentation purposes, so the Firefox Tilt is too visual, with not enough detail

Comment: @Rafael "Layers" is a very commonly used term for those nested levels

Comment: Brian, what's the purpose of doing this? And are you only concerned with the z axis rendering order or what? Does it have to be 3D?

Comment: The purpose is simple: visualize the DOM in some way other than looking at generated HTML code. In, 3D, 2D, doesn't matter. I'm easy with my D's!

Comment: Found something that looks promising. https://gojs.net/latest/samples/DOMTree.html